# resize hovered image on window-width

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover

How can I automatically resize an hovered image depending on the window-width to do not overflow? The Image shown appears on hover the  link. Its set in content: url()

**UPDATE SOLUTION**
`transform: scale` did it

https://jsfiddle.net/6bqfzbj1/

[image]

```
<a class="lightbox">Example</a>
```

CSS

```
a.lightbox:hover {
    position: relative;
}

a.lightbox:hover:after {
    content: url(./bilder/Website-Uebersetzung.png); 
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -300px;
}
```

Comment: you need to provide more details, is this element in a container?

Comment: generally speaking, get rid of position absolute, width 100% and put the element in some form of a container, things should be fine.

Comment: can you put your code inline or jsfiddle for us to see the actual problem?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6bqfzbj1/
on hover the image is too large